# Open Business objects report in iframe

Tags: html, angular, business-objects

I am trying to embed a BO report in my html page using below code. I am seeing this peculiar problem.

When i open this for first time, entire page redirects to BO site and asks for login name and password. However if there is any active session already, then BO report opens with iframe. How to avoid this?

Also is there a way i can avoid this login page from BO (either by redirect or redirect within iframe)? I dont want to hard code user's password, then get a logontoken.

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>BO report is shown below</p>
  <div>
   <iframe src="https://<my company bo url>/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?sIDType=CUID&iDocID=FvMGGFzFzgsAOSQAAABXVbUVAFBWiVbG&sIDType=CUID&sType=wid&sReportPart=UIREF%3ARID%3D143%3ABID%3D45&mode=Part&sRefresh=N&lsSpsEnter%20Acq%20No=134&lsSpsEnter%20Acq%20No1=134&sWindow=Same"></iframe>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have been checking the documentation but could not find any solution for these. My SAP BO version is **SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.2 Support Pack 5 Patch 3 Version: 14.2.5.2776**. We typically use **Enterprise** account to login to BO.

Even though i gave a sample html code here, ultimately i am working to embed BO reports in angular based application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kiriti, were you able to find a solution for this?  I'm having a similar issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Think you need to use SSO or Trusted Auth but trusted auth with BO (unlike Tableau) requires a password as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an issue. This is for security reasons. You can resolve this issue by creating an open document URL of the bobj document which can be authenticated through SAP's Restful web services API. I have written a blog for the same which can be found [here](https://dev.to/adii9/making-an-authentication-less-open-document-url-for-bobj-document-5h5o). Hope this helps.